# Jolt Transform MapRecord to JSON

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I need to flatten a db using nifi. I read in a table based in a PK ID. For each row the nifi content is shown as a MapRecord. I need to pull each field value out of the MapRecord and make it a json property.

> Input:

```
{
   "maxResults": 150,
   "total": 89,
   "issues": "MapRecord[{issueId=1, firstName=Jack, lastName=Smith}]",
   "address": "MapRecord[{addressId=1, street=Mockingbird Lane, town=Timbuktoo}]"
}
```

Notice in the MapRecord nothing is in quotes. I don't know why this is like this. It is obviously not JSON.

I want the result to look like:

> Expected output:

```
{
   "maxResults": 150,
   "total": 89,
   "firstName": "Jack",
   "lastName": "Smith",
   "street": "Mockingbird Lane", 
   "town": "Timbuktoo"
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this using a JOLT transform?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it to solve by applying too many transformation specs. In the first step need to extract the key-value pairs. In order to perform this **split** function within **modify-overwrite-beta** might be used. At the later steps, need to keep the existing pairs(`maxResults`&`total`) and properly combine with the extracted ones using some trick methods such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "i": "=split('}',@(1,issues))",
      "a": "=split('}',@(1,address))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "i": "=split(', ',@(1,i))",
      "a": "=split(', ',@(1,a))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "maxResults": "&",
      "total": "&",
      "i|a": {
        "0": { "1|2": { "@": "theRest" } }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "arr0.&",
      "theRest": { "*": "&" }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=split('=',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "arr0": {
        "*": {
          "@": "arr[1]",
          "$": "arr[0]"
        }
      },
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "arr.[&1]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "arr": {
        "0": null,
        "*": {
          "*": "[&1].@(2,[0].[&])"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": null,
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```